# This operation is only allowed using a successfully authenticated context

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp, certificate, sslstream

I want to make client-server application with tcp encryption, but i have error when i try to send any message: ***This operation is only allowed using a successfully authenticated context.*** I already have: `Certificate = new X509Certificate2("./server.pfx"); SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(Certificate, false, false);` in server and `SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("192.168.0.4");` in client.